# How to tell if AMI is Ubuntu or Amazon Linux?

Tags: boto3, aws-cli

I need a way to automatically find out SSH username for an instance. It requires knowing whether AMI is Amazon Linux or Ubuntu (ec2-user@ for Amazon Linux vs ubuntu@ on Ubuntu images)

Can someone see a way to get this info?

I've been using `image.root_device_name` which seems to be `/dev/xvda` on Amazon Linux `/dev/sda1` on Ubuntu, but I wonder how reliable this is and if there's an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ImageId from:

`ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
ec2.describe_instances()`

Then use the ImageId in `ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=[ImageId1,ImageId2])`

Answer (score 0):

As Shivam mentioned you can get the Operating System from the description inside of "Describe Images' API call. If it is not contained within here though then you would probably have to revert to checking between `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/sda1`. 
You can use the below to pass in the instance id and get the username using boto3

```
import boto3

ec2=boto3.client('ec2')

instance_id = 'i-0defb5cd304ca2d7a'

def find_username(instance_id):
    image_id = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])["Reservations"][0]['Instances'][0]['ImageId']
    image_type = ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=[image_id])['Images'][0]['Description']
    elif 'Amazon Linux' in image_type:
        return 'Username is ec2-user'
    elif 'Ubuntu' in image_type:
        return 'Username is ubuntu'
    else:
        return 'OS is not Amazon Linux or Ubuntu'
```

or using the aws cli (combined with jq)

```
get_username () {
    IMAGE_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $1 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId');
    IMAGE_TYPE=$(aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $IMAGE_ID | jq '.Images[].Description');
    if [[ $IMAGE_TYPE == *"Amazon Linux"* ]]; then
        echo "Username is ec2-user"
    elif [[ $IMAGE_TYPE == *"Ubuntu"* ]]; then
        echo "Username is ubuntu"
    else ;
        echo "OS is not Amazon Linux or Ubuntu"
    fi
}
```

You can run the shell function by just passing the instance id as an arg e.g. `get_username i-xxxxxxxxx`